# Comma before [standalone] 'even'

Tags: punctuation

Do I need to add a comma before 'even' in the following sentence?

> I hold her very dear. As dear as my family even.

OR

> I hold her very dear. As dear as my family, even.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, include the comma.

From [Comma Rules](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/comma-rules.html) at yourdictionary.com:

> 8. Use a comma to signal that the main, independent clause is about to begin (when the sentence begins with something else) or that it is being interrupted. Words that may be used to introduce or interrupt a sentence are: in fact, on the other hand, to tell the truth, yes, no, indeed, well, nevertheless, however, in my opinion, etc.
>
> *The truth, in my opinion, is that we are all guilty in part. Indeed, I know that I am. However, I didn’t pull the trigger. Mrs. Peacock, on the the other hand, did. If you have any doubts about this fact, please check her purse. You will find the gun there, I believe.*

The main clause is "As dear as family". In your example, "even" functions like the last example, "I believe".

Comment: 'As dear as my family' contains no verb. I'd say the comma is optional here, though many would prefer a pause in speech before the intensifying comment 'even'. 'On the other hand'  after 'Not as dear as my family' certainly requires a comma before the pragmatic marker (this one, of the contrastive variety).